# How can I get a list of objects of a specific types contained in a Julia session?

Tags: julia

I have defined several variables working in Julia.
Now I would like to list those variables which are dictionaries (and hence are of `Dict` type)

How do I list all variables of a specific type within a Julia REPL session?

Comment: Please provide enough details in your question so we can entirely figure out the problem. Providing the code you've tried in a code block **(not a picture)** would be encouraging. I recommend you to check the [“How do I ask a good question?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) topic. Specifying the type of the *file* you're working on and the content of the file and the code you've tried would be good enlightenment.

Comment: I answered the question guessing what you want - please edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to get a list of all dictionaries defined in your Julia session.

Supposing you have
`a=Dict()` and `b=Dict()` you can find them with the following code:

```
julia> [f for f in names(Main) if getfield(Main,f) isa AbstractDict]
2-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :a
 :b
```

Comment: That works perfectly @Prezmyslaw, I am new to Julia and programming, so the answer and edits to the question were very useful.